# Find the equation of the plane containing the point $(1, 2, 3)$ and the line $(x, y, z) = (0, 0, -1) + \lambda (2, -2, 1)$

Tags: vectors

Find the equation of the plane containing the point $(1, 2, 3)$ and the line $(x, y, z) = (0, 0, -1) + \lambda (2, -2, 1)$

For this question, do I first

put $\lambda$ into $(2, -2, 1) = (2 \lambda, -2 \lambda, \lambda)$

then add $(2 \lambda, -2 \lambda, \lambda)$ to $(0, 0, -1) = (2 \lambda, -2 \lambda, -1+ \lambda)$

so then $(x, y, z) = (2 \lambda, -2 \lambda, -1+ \lambda)$

then put any value for $\lambda$ (e.g. $1$) and then solve to find the equation between the two points

or is this incorrect?

Comment: This would give another line that is contained in the desired plane. What would you do with that new information?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. A question should be written in such a way that it can be understood even by someone who did not read the title.

Answer (score 1):

You have two points on the plane namely $(1,2,3)$ and $(0,0,−1).$ These two points constitute a vector lying on the plane and another (non-collinear) vector (also lying on the same plane) has been given in the form of direction ratios of the line namely $(2,−2,1).$ Can you now find the direction ratios of the normal to the plane using these two non-collinear vectors lying on that same plane?

**Hint** $:$ What about taking the cross product of these two vectors?

---

**Answer** $:$ $10x + 7y - 6z = 6.$